# what does the multi: true attribute of HTTP_INTERCEPTORS mean?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-http-interceptors

I'm new to Angular and I've just built an interceptor. According to multiple tutorials you have to include the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` in the `app.module` like so:

```
providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true }]
```

I was wondering what that `multi: true` attribute means/does and whether it can be omitted or not.

I've read the [angular.io](https://angular.io) guide about this attribute. They explain it as following:

I don't understand this part:

> Note the multi: true option. This required setting tells Angular that
>   HTTP_INTERCEPTORS is a token for a multiprovider that injects an array
>   of values, rather than a single value.

This sheds some light on the concept but I don't really understand yet when an interceptor is injecting multiple values and when it isn't. For example, my own interceptor is only changing the headers. Does this mean its injecting only a single value?

This is my interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { LoginService } from '../Services/login.service';


@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private loginService:LoginService){}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        console.log("ik zit nu in de interceptor");
        let currentUser = this.loginService.getToken();
        if (currentUser !=="") {

            request = request.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${currentUser}`
                })
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

This is the provide list of app.module

```
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: 'AUTH_URL', useValue: 'http://localhost:8080/auth' },
    { provide: 'API_URL', useValue: 'http://localhost:8080/api' },
    { provide: 'HEADERS', useValue: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) },
    LoginGuard,
    LoginService,
    UserService,
    MessageService
  ],
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#provide-the-interceptor

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the description of the [ValueProvider](https://angular.io/api/core/ValueProvider#properties) interface we can read for the `multi` property:

> When true, `injector` returns an array of instances. This is useful
>   to allow multiple providers to spread across many files to provide
>   configuration information to a common token.

This means that for the token we are providing a value, more than one value (or class) is going to be used.

For instance, see [this example](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/47d9669dbf87ae00b1bff85d99c572834b2d6c2b/client/src/app/core/core.module.ts#L51) (<sub><sup>this is a sample project</sup></sub>) where it is specified for the token `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` to use the classes (`useClass`) `ErrorInterceptor` and `SecurityInterceptor`. In order to get this working, we need to specify `multi: true` so Angular knows that multiple values (or classes) are going to be used.

```
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
  multi: true
},
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: SecurityInterceptor,
  multi: true
},
```

A key point here is that [`HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HTTP_INTERCEPTORS) is a **multi-provider** token. This means that when providing a new value or class for this token the property `multi` is required and it must be set to `true`.

See in the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient) documentation when it is described how to [provide an interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#provide-the-interceptor) the part where it is stated:

> Note the `multi: true` option. This **required setting** tells Angular that
>   HTTP_INTERCEPTORS is a token for a *multiprovider* that injects an array
>   of values, rather than a single value.

Comment: ok so when i have only one Interceptor i can put Multi to false right?

Comment: when i put Multi to false i get this error:  `Mixing multi and non multi provider is not possible for token InjectionToken_HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1`. I don't understand because there are no other interceptors present in the providers list. I do provide APP_BASE_REF but i'm not sure if that has anything to do with the error. Its really strange. Guess i better put it back to true then.

Comment: @Maurice, Yes, so far I've never seen providing an interceptor with this property to `false` or omitted. Not being so with other providers, where you can even omit this property. It would be interesting to see an scenario as the one you describe (if possible at all), where  a value or class is used to provide an `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` with `multi` to false, though. Maybe if you have a github repo, drop a link and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: please see my opening post, i've placed the interceptor and provide list in it.

Comment: @Maurice after digging a bit more in the angular documentation I found that in the case for  the token `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ` this property is required and must be set to `true` because it is  a _multiprovider_ token. I updated my answer, see the last part.

Comment: @Maurice:

Actually, there isn't the only HTTP Interceptor in that list, it's got the ones that come with Angular as well.