# Angular interceptor is not adding custom param in requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9, angular-http-interceptors

I use Angular 9 and i want to add the country name in all requests going to the back end.

I found a blog explaining how to add a request param with interceptor

```
import {
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
} from "@angular/common/http"
import { Observable } from "rxjs"

export class CountryInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const cloneReq = req.clone({
            params: req.params.set(
                "country",
                "France"
            ),
        })
        return next.handle(cloneReq)
    }
}
```

This is my app.modules

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxShimmerLoadingModule,
    SplashScreenModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    HighlightModule,
    LightboxModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    InlineSVGModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    CookieService,
    {
      provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: {
        coreLibraryLoader: () => import('highlight.js/lib/core'),
        languages: {
          xml: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/xml'),
          typescript: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/typescript'),
          scss: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/scss'),
          json: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/json')
        },
      },
    },
    IpInterceptorService,
    {
      provide : APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory : getIpService,
      deps: [IpInterceptorService, HttpClient],
      multi : true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }

export  function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

/**
 * Call the service use to get the ip adress of the user, then the country
 * @param ipInterceptorService
 */
export function getIpService(ipInterceptorService : IpInterceptorService) {
  return ()=> ipInterceptorService.init();
}
```

But it doesn't work. When i check my request i don't have the country in the params. What did i miss ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks good? Did you actually provide the interceptor in app.module?

Comment: @MikeOne, no, how could I do this ?

Comment: That explains then :-). Plenty examples available, like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141132/what-does-the-multi-true-attribute-of-http-interceptors-mean

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks a lot. You are my saviour today.

Comment: You’re welcome. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to provide the interceptor in a correct way.

In the respective module you need to provide it like this:

```js
{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ,useClass: CountryInterceptorService, multi:true}
```

See documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#provide-the-interceptor